# Sass doesn't get compiled

Tags: sass, webpack, vue.js, webpack-style-loader

My scss files are not getting compiled. It doesn't understand what I do with my code. I want to be able to use Sass instead of CSS but I can't find the right way to compile Sass.

I am using the webpack template with Vue.js

My webpack config file looks like this:

```
var path = require('path')
var utils = require('./utils')
var config = require('../config')
var vueLoaderConfig = require('./vue-loader.conf')

function resolve (dir) {
return path.join(__dirname, '..', dir)
}

module.exports = {
entry: {
app: './src/main.js',
},
output: {
path: config.build.assetsRoot,
filename: '[name].js',
publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
  ? config.build.assetsPublicPath
  : config.dev.assetsPublicPath
},
resolve: {
extensions: ['.js', '.vue', '.json'],
alias: {
  'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
  '@': resolve('src'),
}
},
module: {
rules: [
  {
    test: /\.vue$/,
    loader: 'vue-loader',
    options: vueLoaderConfig
  },
  {
    test: /\.scss$/,
    use: [ 'style-loader','css-loader','sass-loader' ],
    loaders: ['style', 'css', 'sass']
  },
  {
    test: /\.js$/,
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    include: [resolve('src'), resolve('test')]
  },
  {
    test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)(\?.*)?$/,
    loader: 'url-loader',
    query: {
      limit: 10000,
      name: utils.assetsPath('img/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
    }
  },
  {
    test: /\.(woff2?|eot|ttf|otf)(\?.*)?$/,
    loader: 'url-loader',
    query: {
      limit: 10000,
      name: utils.assetsPath('fonts/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
    }
  }
]
}
}
```

Comment: You want to use `scss` into the VueJS Single File Components ?

Comment: Use in component <style lang="scss">

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it is to have a single `scss` file as an entry. This is where all your different scss file gets imported. Something like [this](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/blob/master/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap.scss). Then you import that `scss` file in source code of your js entry file (in this case `./src/main.js`). So when webpack reads your `main.js` it will see `import './myscssfile.scss'` and looks for a loader (or I think it does). Here is how I do my scss module in webpack2:

```
module: {
 rules: [
  // my js stuff
  { test: /\.js$/, enforce: 'pre', loader: 'eslint-loader', exclude: /node_modules/ },
  
  // my scss stuff
  {
    test: /\.scss$/,
    use: [
      {
        loader: 'style-loader'
      },
      {
        loader: 'css-loader',
        options: {
          modules: true,
          importLoaders: 2,
          sourceMap: true,
          localIdentName: '[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
        }
      },
      {
        loader: 'autoprefixer-loader',
        options: {
          browsers: 'last 2 version'
        }
      },
      {
        loader: 'sass-loader',
        options: {
          outputStyle: 'expanded',
          sourceMap: true
        }
      }
    ]
  }
 ]
}
```

I hope it works.

Answer (score -1):

Just use `<style lang="sass"></style` in your component. Let me know if it helps.